# How to re-attach chewed dishwasher wire

Tags: electrical, dishwasher

I have a Whirlpool Quiet Partner II which has a wire chewed through by a rodent.  The wire is on the water inlet valve control.

I can see what needs to be attached where, and there is enough slack I believe to just reattach - but I can’t tell how to use this particular connector (and how to do this correctly and safely).  How do I remove the small bit of wire from the connector and then reattach?  Only about 0.5cm of wire is remaining in the connector.  Pulling on the wire doesn’t seem to remove it, using pliers even.  What am I missing?  Does the connector come apart in some way?

I’ve attached a few pictures (and can take more if useful).

[image: Wire attachment]
[image: Wire attachment]

Comment: you are asking how to reattach wires to a connector, yet the pictures do not show how the wire attaches to the connector .. please try to take clearer pictures ... try to make the connector fill most of the picture

Comment: In general, the terminals lock into the housing. There’s probably a spot that you can press in with a tool to release the terminal. Be careful. These terminals are generally not designed to be reused.

Comment: While you might be able to fix this if you could find a replacement pin for that connector, that seems unlikely.  Your best bet might be to replace the entire part that includes that connector.

Comment: @jwh20 It looks like this connects to the overfill float (or rather the support below it), presumably turning off the water when the overfill float is at its maximum. I could replace that I suppose but I don’t see any way to buy the wire - when I search the part, WPW10175383, none of the pictures suggest they include the wire harness. I suppose the wire has another part number but I haven’t been able to figure out what it is!

Comment: @jsotola I will try to get better ones attached (the mobile app is misbehaving with attachments right now) but the connector is quite small so it’s hard to get the picture to focus much bigger.

Comment: You might try grabbing the wire with a needlenose and twist it back and forth pulling slightly apart. As stated about, these connectors aren't really designed to be used over and you'd have to tin the wire to reinsert it.  Can you just cut the whole connector out and splice the wires together with wire nuts?

Comment: I agree with DoxyLover , some times these wires are pressed into a v that cuts the insulation and holds the wire many times the plastic is heated to hold the wire in place , hot glue works as a replacement, I have in some cases done like Jack recommends and removed the socket and direct wired by soldering to the board.